# Connection Problem with "Magento Google Content API for Shopping" Extension

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, google-api, mage-googleshopping

I am having problems with the "Google Content API for Shopping" Magento Extension 
I am using Magento 1.9.1 and I'm based in the UK.

I've installed the latest version of Google Content API for Shopping, but I can't get it to work. It's installed fine; I can enter settings in Configuration>Sales.
Unfortunately, I don't know what to enter!

I tried the following:

- Account ID = My Merchant Account ID
- Account Login = My Google User Name
- Account Password = My Google Password
- Account Type = Hosted or Google

I then go to Catalogue>Google Content>Manage Items
I tick the products I want to upload to Google Shopping, select "Add to Google Content" in the Action menu.
Unfortunately, the result is the following message:

> The product cannot be added to Google Content. Unable to connect to Google Content. Please, check Account settings in configuration.Error: Unable to Connect to ssl://www.google.com:443. Error #110: connection timed out

I tried contacting the extension vendor (Magento) a few weeks ago, but they have not responded.

Can anyone help? Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a third party extension.

Comment: Third part extensions are allowed to be discussed:
"Magento Stack Exchange is for users of and developers working with the Magento e-Commerce platform. Questions which involve custom code or extensions should include relevant code and, where applicable, an indication that the custom coder or extension vendor has been contacted for support."

Comment: Can someone please explain to me how this question is off-topic when it clearly says in the community scope that extensions CAN be discussed?

Comment: The only way anyone can attempt to reproduce the issues you describe is by installing the extension you describe. The reason the community here doesn't for the vast majority of cases offer any support for third party extensions is purely because there are just too many - it's an entirely unrealistic proposition. If you are however able to narrow down a problem to some specific code (as per the guidelines you reference) and post that, rather than just usability instructions on an extension people don't have installed then you will have much better luck.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. You are closing the question because you think (in your opinion) there won't be anyone to answer it, despite it being within the scope of the forum? Surely that is up to the people in the forum to decide! By all means close it if no one has answered my question in a week, but to close it within 2 hours doesn't give anyone the opportunity to answer the question! In addition, my question is about usability instructions - which logically people must know about in order to know the answer about specific code, which you say is allowed to be asked about!

Comment: At some point a line has to be drawn as to what it is practical to help people with and what it is not. The Magento core is a massive code base, and while code examples are fine with third party extensions, just usage instructions don't make it easy for people to help. Remember that we are all just regular developers/users of Magento who assist as time allows, so realistically there's a very slim chance that a user will know a specific extension issue at the time a questions is asked. Closing questions is an attempt to keep the forum relevant with information useful to many different users.

Comment: So considering Magento are ignoring my request for support, and this is the ONLY semi-official support site for Magento, what do you recommend I do? I only need basic instructions for a very popular extension.

Comment: I would suggest either tracking the issue down to some problematic code which can be posted here, or get yourself a developer.

Comment: There is *no* problematic code. Which part of "I only need basic instructions" don't you understand? And I *am* the developer!

Comment: Well if you are the developer, get debugging... I am sure you can determine what information you need to enter looking at how it's used.

Comment: That's the thing - I *don't* know. That's why I am using a support forum, where I expect some sort of help. Clearly I was wrong.